# Changing curve resolution depending on steepness in Geo Nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I want to change the curve resolution, depending on its steepness. The more "you have to steer" the less res it should have.

Reason for that being that I want to give the curve a profile, which starts clipping in itself when the angle of the curve gets too steep.

Basically im looking for a way, to change the length input in the Resample Curve node, depending on the angle of the spline, compared to the one before.

I dont know how to pull all that off tho.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proposal :

[image]

We're making use of the [Field at Index](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/field_at_index.html) node to compute the relative distance between Control Point (CP) at indices  $n$ and $n-1$, and $n$ and $n+1$.

If three consecutive CP are in a straight line, the distance (length) between the two subtracted positions will be very close to $0$. If however there is a curve between the three points, the length will increase. You can use this to dynamically cull control points based on this factor.

If the spline is not cyclic, we don't want to cull the first and last CPs. We remove them from the selection with a [Boolean Math](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/boolean_math.html) node set to *Subtract*.

Here's me playing with the settings :

[image]

[image]